If $f(x),g(x) \in R[x], Z(f) \cap Z(g) \neq \varnothing$ and $\deg g(x) < \deg f(x)$, then can $f(x) = f_1(x)f_2(x)$ where $f_1(x),f_2(x) \in R[x]$?
Let $f(x), g(x) \in R[x]$, where $R = \mathbb{Z}/(p^k \mathbb{Z})$ and $\deg g(x) < \deg f(x)$. If $Z(f) \cap Z(g) \neq \varnothing$, where $Z(f) = \{x : f(x) =0\}$, then can we say that $f(x)$ factors? Here $f(x)$ factored means there exists two nontrivial polynomials $f_1(x), f_2(x) \in R[x]$ such that $f(x) = f_1(x)f
_2(x)$.
Now, if $k = 1$, then $R$ is a field, and hence, we can take $\gcd(f(x),g(x))$ as a factor of $f(x)$. But is it possible for general $k>1$? Because gcd can't be defined if it is not a domain.
Is there any definition for extended gcd or like Bezout identity so that we can say that $f(x)$ is factored?

If $\alpha$ is a root of $f$ then $x-\alpha$ divides $f$. This is true over any commutative unital ring.

Yes, that's true, but $f$ factored means $f =gh$, where $g,h \ R[x]$. But we can't say that $x - \alpha \in R[x]$. Maybe I should update this part. Thanks for pointing out.

If you don't like what \emptyset, $\emptyset$ looks like (and I wouldn't blame you), then use \varnothing, $\varnothing$, not \phi.

I don't understand your last comment. If $\alpha\in R$ is a root, then $x-\alpha\in R[x]$ divides $f$.

Also you'll probably want to exclude $g=0$, otherwise $f=x$, $g=0$ is a boring counterexample.

@ArturoMagidin I appreciate the information you provided. I will take care in the future.

@Afntu Then what do you mean by $Z(f)$? Where do these roots belong?

@anankElpis, it is not necessary that all the roots of $f$ are also in $R$. for example, $f(x) = x^2 + 1 \in \Bbb{R}[x]$ , but roots are in $\Bbb{C}$.

@Mark roots live in some extension ring.
